# How Root CA's Certificate validates the certificate signed by its private key, when the Root CA's certificate itself is self signed

Tags: ssl, openssl

I am trying to understand how a self-signed certificate created by ROOT CA, can be used to validate (decrypt) a certificate signed by the private key used by ssCA.

I currently dont need an external CA, so i decided to use my own self signed Root CA, to sign other certificates.

Self Signed Certificate by Root CA is created using a private key (root.key). The certificate contains the public key of Root CA and some meta info.

Now if i use the root.key to sign another certificate C, how does the C can be validated by the self signed certificate of Root CA? (Isnt the self-signed certificate of Root CA encrypted by the root.key itself, and it has its public key as part of the signature. How will that signature be decrypted to obtain the exact public key?)

Comment: I figured out that the hash (of Root CA's public key and meta) will be signed(encrypted) and not the while public key itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't the self-signed certificate of Root CA encrypted by the root.key itself, and it has its public key as part of the signature

Signing and encrypting are orthogonal, i.e. data can be signed but not encrypted, they can be encrypted but not signed or they can be both signed and encrypted.

A certificate is signed, not encrypted.